# Spark with replicated Cassandra nodes

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I found article where author advices to use next Spark-Cassandra architecture schema(Spark Slave for each Cassandra node):
[image]

I have N Cassandra nodes. All nodes are complete replicas of each other. Is some sense to run Spark slave for each Cassandra node in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. The Spark-Cassandra connector is data locality aware, i.e. each Spark node co-located with a Cassandra node will make sure to only process the local Cassandra data, which avoids shuffling lots of data across the network. You can find out how this works by watching a talk by Russell Spitzer on this topic [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikCzILOpYvA).